# Firebase realtime database Cannot record touch move without a touch start. Touch Mov

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

enter code herein my Expo app I am using googleSignin as login method, so afterlogin I want to collect Name, email, photo, and post it to the database

> import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

```
    const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    GoogleSignin.configure({
        webClientId: 'My_ID',
      });


      function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
        setUser(user);
        if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
        return subscriber; 
      }, []);

      async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
        await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true });
        const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
        const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
        // Sign-in the user with the credential
        const user_sign_in = auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
        user_sign_in.then((user)=>{
            console.log(user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })

        const userRef = database.ref(`/user_id/${user.uid}`);
             userRef.set({
             email: signInResult.user.email,
             name: signInResult.user.displayName,
             photoURL: signInResult.user.photoURL,
             });
             
      }
```

but I am getting this Error

```
 WARN  Warning: Cannot record touch move without a touch start.
Touch Move: {"identifier":0,"pageX":311.22845458984375,"pageY":496.953125,"timestamp":754177246}
Touch Bank: []
 WARN  Warning: Cannot record touch end without a touch start.
Touch End: {"identifier":0,"pageX":304.1109619140625,"pageY":495.1422119140625,"timestamp":754177252}
Touch Bank: []
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is mistake in code, You **should wait till the promise resolved** by **signInWithCredential** method.

Have a try using below changes in code of **onGoogleButtonPress** function:

```
async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
  await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true});
  const {idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
  const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
  // Sign-in the user with the credential
  const user_sign_in = auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
  user_sign_in
    .then(user => {
      console.log(user);
      const userRef = database().ref(`/user_id/${user.uid}`);
      userRef.set({
        email: user.email,
        name: user.displayName,
        photoURL: user.photoURL,
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! it solved it, Thanks a million Vicky